# Reverse geocoded address

Tags: visualforce, geolocation

Is it possible to get the address and map it into Account's standard addressess based on the long lat?
I have a code which gets the current long and lat and updates the details of the account in button click. Im just wondering if the long lat can get also the address of the area atleast city, region,country.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd need an external data provider for this. For example, you could use Google's [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to feed it a latitude and longitude and get back the most likely address, including country, region, city, and street. There are some providers on the AppExchange that have applications that do this as well, so it's definitely possible.